# Connect to Mysql with PHPStorm on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: server, mysql

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 with the following on two Systems

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server-Typ: MariaDB
Server-Version: 10.1.25-MariaDB- - Ubuntu 17.04
Protokoll-Version: 10
Benutzer: root@localhost
Server-Zeichensatz: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

nginx/1.10.3
Datenbank-Client Version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: fffffffffff $
PHP-Erweiterung: mysqliDokumentation curlDokumentation mbstringDokumentation
PHP-Version: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.17.04.1
```

They are the excat same version - tho I cannot connect with the one PC to MYSQL via Phpstorm. The settings there are also the same. Is there an known issue with PHPStorm and Mysql on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the bin_address I set up for testing...

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

and change it to

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

then restart

```
sudo mysql service restart
```